# How to write unit test for method which instantiates collaborators inside itself?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmockito

Method code like so:

```
- (void)downloadSomething:(NSString *)url {
    Downloader *downloader = [[Downloader alloc] initWithUrl:url];
    NSData *data = [downloader download];
    FileCache *cache = [[FileCache alloc] initWithFile:@"download.cache"];
    cache.data = data;
    [cache save];
}
```

I think I should mock Downloader and FileCache to verify if it works well.
I have thought about change signature like that: `downloadSomething:(NSString *)url downloader:(Downloader *)downloader cache:(FileCache *)cache`, but it seem to have to do much work before call this methods, that's not what I want.

I am using ocmockito.

Besides, is there a guide to make writing code more testable ?

---

edit: 2017-01-16 14:54:23

Is this a good idea to write two method like:

```
- (void)updateCacheWithUrl:(NSString *)url 
                downloader:(Downloader *)downloader 
                 fileCache:(FileCache *)fileCache; // for testing
- (void)updateCacheWithUrl:(NSString *)url; // call above method with (url, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a collaborator is instantiated inside a method, this creates tight coupling. The difficulty of testing this leads us to explore other designs.

One way is to pass them in. This is what I'd normally do. Then I would make a simpler version that provides default objects for production code.

But in your example, the `url` is passed to the `Downloader`, which makes this harder. This suggests that the current design of `downloadSomething:` violates the Single Responsibility Principle. It's doing two things: downloading, and caching.

So splitting up these responsibilities would probably make things easier to test.

Comment: Maybe I should rename method to 'updateCacheWithUrl:'

Comment: I have thought a lot. Wherever I wrote `Downloader *downloader = [[Downloader alloc] initWithUrl:url];`, it will make that method hard to test. Should I wrote it in private method and do not write test for it ?

Comment: @ccnyou If you make Downloader in one method, I'd pass in a block parameter that acts as a factory. If it's across multiple methods, change it from a parameter to a property.

Comment: I wonder what's Single Responsibility Principle boundaries ? Is download method that working for new downloading task and continue exists task(same url) violates the Single Responsibility Principle. If it it, should I split up to two public methods or (one public + tow private) methods ? I don't want to check if task exists before call this download mehtod.

Comment: @ccnyou Don't try to overthink it. The important thing is to make progress, even if the path is flawed. In the process, you'll learn more.

Comment: So I am trying to learn more by asking some one like you who is experienced in it. /smile

Comment: I'd add a block property:
`@property (nonatomic, readonly) Downloader *(^makeDownloader)(NSURL *);`
set by the initializer. You can then have a simpler initializer that provides a default. For an example, see http://qualitycoding.org/tdd-deferred-design/ where I do MD5 calculation. First I start with by isolating it in a method that a test can override. Then I refactor away from subclass-and-override by injecting a block instead.